# What units of ether does ethereumjs-tx use

Tags: ethereumjs-tx

Trying to follow this [example](https://github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-tx/blob/master/examples/transactions.js) 100 wei seems very low for the gas price. Is it using a different unit? I'm also slightly unsure if the value should be hex or decimal, or if it accepts both

Answer (score 1):

On the main github page, the value `0x09184e72a000` is used. [Converting](http://decimal-to-binary.com/decimal-to-binary-converter-online.html?id=12405) that to base 10, we get this figure: 10,000,000,000,000 (10 quadrillions).

According to the [gas station](https://ethgasstation.info/), we can consider the average price (as of May 2018) to be 12 **gwei**, or 12,000,000,000 (12 billions) **wei**.

We can thus deduce that the amount set my `ethereumjs-tx` creators was set in **wei**, so that your contract will always have enough gas. They also perhaps assumed you'll be using it on a testnet first.